# How do I load a sound file using initWithContentsOfURL:error:?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

How do I gain access to a `crashSound.wav` file I've put in my Supporting Files folder of my xCode Project? Because the following code isn't working :

```
@interface Game()
{
    // code...

    AVAudioPlayer *crashSound;

    // code...
}
@end

@implementation Game

- (id) init 
{ 
    // code...

    NSURL *crashSoundFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"crashSound" ]; // <--PROBLEM

    crashSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:crashSoundFile error:NULL];

    // code...
}
-(void) play // this is my "main" method that will be called once the playButton is pressed
{
   [crashSound play];[crashSound play];[crashSound play];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@"crashSound"` is not a valid URL. You must supply an actual URL.

URLs to images, sounds, etc. (resources) in your project are not predictable at compile-time, and must be generated at run-time. This is easy using `NSBundle`.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *crashSoundFile = [bundle URLForResource: @"crashSound" withExtension: @"wav"];
```

Ta da.

Answer (score 0):

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/soundfile.extension", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];